# How to query CloudWatch usage in VPC Flow logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena, amazon-vpc

We store all VPC flow logs in a centralized bucket. Now I want to check how much of the traffic (through the NAT) is related to CloudWatch.
I know that the most expensive thing of CloudWatch is the putLogEvents but still we want to check if it's a good idea to create a VPC Interface endpoint for CloudWatch (not only for security reasons, but we also want to check if it will reduce some NAT GW traffic).

Now I'm looking for an Athena Query to retrieve CW related data through the NAT.
I did the setup described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/vpc-flow-logs.html). The examples work, but I'm struggling to find a correct query to find the amount of data that go through the NAT because of CloudWatch. Can someone help me to get started?

I can query for top 10 destinations like this:

```
SELECT dstaddr, SUM(bytes) AS total_bytes
FROM twgflowlogs.awslogs
GROUP BY dstaddr
ORDER BY total_bytes DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But I want to query on "where destination is CloudWatch".

Thanks!

Comment: You first need to retrieve the IP ranges used by cloudwatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html and then use some string splitting to filter out the dstaddrs that are in that range https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/vpc-flow-logs.html

Comment: @luk2302 thanks seems interesting, but I can't find CloudWatch as service in the json list (or in the allowed values of the service).

Comment: That is unfortunate, then I do not know what to do... :/

Answer (score 0):

Use filter on the dstdomainname field instead of the dstaddr field with LIKE operator to filter for CloudWatch traffic.

```
SELECT SUM(bytes) AS total_bytes
FROM twgflowlogs.awslogs
WHERE dstdomainname LIKE '%.logs.%'
AND dstdomainname LIKE '%.amazonaws.com%'
```

Comment: dstdomainname does not exist in my table as column (created from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/vpc-flow-logs.html). I'll recreate the table and check if it does something.